# Search filter UI for recent posts

Tags: feature-request, search, filtering

It would be useful, and probably easy to implement, to have a search filter UI for questions or answers posted recently, for example:

- past 24 hours
- past 7 days
- past 30 days
- past 12 months
- any time

Especially when sorting by "most votes". This would be more user-friendly than advanced search options like `created:1d..`.

Answer (score 1):

This already exists as an [advanced search operator](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/searching); e.g. [searching for `created:1d..`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=created%3a1d..) gives all posts from the last 24 hours.

> #### Dates
>
> You can use specific dates or date ranges to narrow results down to posts created or active within a certain time period, using the following operators:
>
> - `created:` to specify when the posts were created
> - `lastactive:` for posts active in a specified time period

> Relative dates in a range (`1y..`) look back to the same date in the previous period - e.g., if you want to see all the posts active in the last three months, use `lastactive:3m..` On April 15, that will show posts from January 15 up to the most recently active.

Comment: Yes, I realized that and edited my question. It would be more user-friendly to make this part of the search filter UI. Especially, the difference between `1m` and `1m..` is really unintuitive.